# Building a recurrence relation for this code?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I need to build a recurrence relation for the following algorithm (T(n) stands for number of elemental actions) and find it's time complexity:

```
Alg (n)
{
    if (n < 3) return;
    for i=1 to n
    {
       for j=i to 2i
       {
           for k=j-i to j-i+100
              write (i, j, k);
       }
    }

    for i=1 to 7
       Alg(n-2);
 }
```

I came to this Recurrence relation (don't know if it's right):

> T(n) = 1 if n < 3
>
> T(n) = 7T(n-2)+100n<sup>2</sup> otherwise.

I don't know how to get the time complexity, though.

Is my recurrence correct? What's the time complexity of this code?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the code to see what the recurrence should be.

First, let's look at the loop:

```
    for i=1 to n
    {
       for j=i to 2i
       { 
           for k=j-i to j-i+100
               write (i, j, k);
       }
    }
```

How much work does this do? Well, let's begin by simplifying it. Rather than having `j` count up from `i` to `2i`, let's define a new variable `j'` that counts up from `0` to `i`. This means that `j'` = `j - i`, and so we get this:

```
    for i=1 to n
    {
       for j' = 0 to i
       { 
           for k=j' to j'+100
               write (i, j' + i, k);
       }
    }
```

Ah, that's much better! Now, let's also rewrite `k` as `k'`, where `k'` ranges from 1 to 100:

```
    for i=1 to n
    {
       for j' = 0 to i
       { 
           for k'= 1 to 100
               write (i, j' + i, k' + j);
       }
    }
```

From this, it's easier to see that this loop has time complexity Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), since the innermost loop does O(1) work, and the middle loop will run 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) times. Notice that it's not exactly 100n<sup>2</sup> because the summation isn't exactly n<sup>2</sup>, but it is close.

Now, let's look at the recursive part:

```
for i=1 to 7
    Alg(n-2);
```

For starters, this is just plain silly! There's no reason you'd ever want to do something like this. But, that said, we can say that this is 7 calls to the algorithm on an input of size n - 2.

Accordingly, we get this recurrence relation:

> T(n) = 7T(n - 2) + Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)  [if n ≥ 3]
>
> T(n) = Θ(1) [otherwise]

Now that we have the recurrence, we can start to work out the time complexity. That ends up being a little bit tricky. If you think about how much work we'll end up doing, we'll get that

- There's 1 call of size n.
- There's 7 calls of size n - 2.
- There's 49 calls of size n - 4.
- There's 343 calls of size n - 6.
- ...
- There's 7<sup>k</sup> calls of size n - 2k

From this, we immediately get a lower bound of Ω(7<sup>n/2</sup>), since that's the number of calls that will get made. Each call does O(n<sup>2</sup>) work, so we can get an upper boudn of O(n<sup>2</sup>7<sup>n/2</sup>). The true value lies somewhere in there, though I honestly don't know how to figure out what it is. Sorry about that!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A formal method is to do the following:

[image]

[image]

The **prevailing** order of growth can be intuitively inferred from the source code, when it comes to the number of recursive calls.

An algorithm with 2 recursive calls has a complexity of 2^n; with 3 recursive calls the complexity 3^n and so on.